# Spring circular references when running on Mac OS

Tags: java, spring, macos, maven

I have been working on a Java application with Spring version 4.0.7 on a Windows machine which has worked fine over the past few years. Recently we have the requirement for developers to use MacBook Pro to develop and we've immediately had issues with circular references within our Spring configuration when running the application (build with Maven is fine). Does anyone know any reason why running Spring applications on Windows machines would be any different to Mac OS machines?

The Java version we are using is 1.7.0.80,
Details of exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reactor': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:446)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:420)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
... 127 more
```

Comment: Double-check if the setups are identical, OS shouldn't matter.

Comment: Consider upgrading your version of Java and your version of Spring.  The new versions of Spring use Java 8 as a baseline.

Comment: Yes I thought the setups shouldn't matter aka-one. Very confusing!

Comment: Ideally we don't want to change the code or versions to get it working on a Mac

Comment: Unfortunately we're going to need more information. Can you post the config/code for `reactor`? Otherwise there's just not enough information to answer this question and I can almost _guarantee_ this has nothing to do with the Windows/Mac cross over. It's likely just a config issue that cropped up while either setting up a new developer or was otherwise hidden previously.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out first: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/115998-circular-dependency-identification-inconsistent

Apparently, in some scenarios, the underlying OS api for listing files returns a different order.

However, you might try to solve the problem by either changing the order of the packages to scan in the `@ComponentScan()` annotation or by using the `@dependsOn("reactor")` annotation on the class that is triggering the exception.